# display only the first elements in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to display only the first elements in a 2d array but its only displaying the 2nd arrays first element. How do I do this?

```js
var foods = [
  ["name", "category", "servingOz", "calories_serving"],
  ["name2", "category2", "servingOz2", "calories_serving2"],
];

function getfoodNames() {
  for (i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < foods[i].length; j++) {
      document.getElementById("foods").innerHTML = foods[i][0].toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the innerHTML of the food element every pass of the for loop. So only the last one will be presented.

You should use the += operation:

```
document.getElementById('foods').textContent += foods[i][0];
```

I advise against using innerHTML, since it is dangerous.

**Update**

I just now noticed the inner for loop is unnecessary, so you can remove it altogether:

```
for(let i=0; i < foods.length; i++) {

    document.getElementById('foods').textContent += foods[i][0];

}
```

Comment: No problem! ^^ And by the way, your second for loop is unnecessary! Since you never use your "j" variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<foods.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById('foods').innerHTML += foods[i][0].toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
var arr = [
  ["name", "category", "servingOz", "calories_serving"],
  ["name2", "category2", "servingOz2", "calories_serving2"]
];

arr.forEach(el => foods.innerText += ' ' + el[0]);
```

```html
<div id="foods"></div>
```